# Arduino Leonardo isn't detected by Linux Mint on serial port /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: arduino-leonardo, uploading

I'm working on Linux Mint 18 Sarah (earlier Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) system. I've installed Arduino IDE using command `sudo apt-get install arduino` and I've added me dialout group using `sudo usermod -aG dialout $(whoami)`. This is results of executing `groups` command:

```
hubert@hubert-SATELLITE-C660D ~ $ groups
dialout adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare hubert
```

When I try upload following code to Arduino Leonardo:

```cpp
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(500);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(500);               // wait for a second
}
```

orange LED marked with L letter on my board blinks and next I get following error:

```cpp
Wielkość binarna szkicu: 4 736 bajtów (maksymalnie: 28 672 bajtów)
processing.app.debug.RunnerException: Couldn’t find a Leonardo on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.
    at processing.app.debug.AvrdudeUploader.uploadViaBootloader(AvrdudeUploader.java:153)
    at processing.app.debug.AvrdudeUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(AvrdudeUploader.java:67)
    at processing.app.Sketch.upload(Sketch.java:1671)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1627)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1599)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On my IDE Arduino shows on `/dev/ttyACM0` serial port. When I try running this IDE on root privileges, I get the same error. On root privileges serial port is changing from `/dev/ttyACM0` to `/dev/ttyACM1`, from `/dev/ttyACM1` to `/dev/ttyACM2` etc. I tried different USB cabels and reset Arduino but these ways nothing help. On Windows 7 my Arduino works and Arduino IDE uploads code without problems. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Read this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Comment: FWIW my money is on ModemManager.

Comment: Are you create ModemManager app?

Comment: No. "my money is on..." is a British idiom meaning "If I were a gambling man and I placed a bet on the cause, I would bet on it being ModemManager".

Comment: What exactly is ModemManager?

Comment: It's explained in the link I posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44566/discussion-between-hubot-and-majenko).

Comment: Have you read that article? Have you tried the things in it? Until you do I cannot help you further.

Comment: Yes, I executed these instructions.

Comment: I've one more question. Did you write this guide for only Linux Mint distribution?

Comment: That guide is generic for most Linux distros, but I use Debian which is what Ubuntu is based on, which in turn is what Mint is based on.

Comment: So what was the outcome of disabling / removing ModemManager?